# C# TableLayoutPanel MouseMove Too Much CPU

Tags: c#, mousemove

greetings. i have an issue with the following code. for some reason whenever it is executed it is consuming around 60% of the CPU. this is strange, and was wondering if you had any comments?

```
    private void HomeTableLayoutPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        PictureBox HomeCurrentPicBox = (PictureBox)(HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetChildAtPoint(e.Location));
        TableLayoutPanelCellPosition HomeCurrentPosition = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(-1, -1);

        if (HomeCurrentPicBox != null)
        {
            HomeCurrentPosition = HomeTableLayoutPanel.GetCellPosition(HomeCurrentPicBox);
            gameFormToolTip.SetToolTip(HomeTableLayoutPanel, GameModel.alphaCoords(HomeCurrentPosition.Column) + "," + HomeCurrentPosition.Row.ToString());
        }
    }
```

thank you for your time.

edit: im told it is sampling too often. in some aspects this is true in my other semi working code. but my question is too lengthy and i cant explain it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't you just attach to the mousemove event of the (each?) `PictureBox`?

Comment: no i cannot because there are 100 of them. the code will be inefficient.

Comment: i get what you are are saying. point to a single event method for all picturebox members. got it.